# How convert variable string [] to float

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

How can I convert a string to a float?

This is my code:

```
string A[3] = {"20","21"};
float convertA ;

convertA = atof (A[1]) ;
cout << convertA << endl ;
```

And this is what's displayed:

> -1 #lND

Any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Does it even compile? Are those strings `std::string`s?

Comment: This does not compile. You want: `convertA = atof(A[1].c_str());`, unless `string` is something else than `std::string`; I cannot tell with just 4 lines of code.

Comment: Use `std::stof` on `std::string` variables instead. `atof` is for C strings i.e. `const char *`

Comment: the output is still issuing -1. # IND

Comment: i'm use using namespace std.

Comment: No, it's outputting `21` try compiling it again.

Comment: This is not your complete code. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: I think `std::stof` is not available with VS2012.

Comment: the program runs, before I put it in the function and display the data in the function and call it in play, after I move the results of data outside this function successfully, thanks a lot for the help

Comment: Your code is incomplete; in particular, it seems to be missing a `main()` function and at least one `#include`. Please [edit] your code so it's a [mcve] of your problem (including any necessary inputs, but preferably not needing any), then we can try to reproduce and solve it. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the man page of `atof()`, `convertA` should be type of `double`.

```
double atof (const char* str);
```

And

```
convertA = atof (A[1]) ; /* it won't work */
```

It should be

```
convertA = atof(A[1].c_str());
```

Working Code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main() {
        std::string A[3] = {"20","21"};
        double convertA ;

        //convertA = atof (A[1]) ;
        convertA = atof(A[1].c_str());
        std::cout << convertA << std::endl ;

        return 0;
}
```

**Edit :** to convert string to float you can use `stof()` instead of `atof()`. find the more  information here http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stof/

Comment: There is [std::stof](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof) available.

Comment: yup @super you are right.

Comment: the output is still issued -1. # IND

Comment: @rafinsanovriardhira Compile the code which I answered, it will work.

Comment: The data=21 its true, but there a variable -1.#IND

Comment: @rafinsanovriardhira which variable prints -1

Comment: the program runs, before I put it in the function and display the data in the function and call it in play, after I move the results of data outside this function successfully, thanks a lot for the help